# error: invalid use of member <...> in static member function

Tags: c++, sorting, static

I'm encountering this error when I'm trying to use the content of my map 'freq' declared as a class variable, inside my comparator function for sorting the vector(using map to sort the vector elements by frequency). Can anyone highlight where am i going wrong and what should I do?
Here's the code:

```
class Solution {
    map<int, int> freq;
public:
    static bool comp(int a, int b){
        if(a!=b){
            int c1 = freq[a];
            int c2 = freq[b];
            if(c1!=c2)
                return c1<c2;
            else{
                return a>b;
            }
        }
        return a>b;
    }
    vector<int> frequencySort(vector<int>& nums) {
        for(int i:nums){
            freq[i]++;
        }
        sort(nums.begin(), nums.end(), comp);
        return nums;
    }
};
```

Error is:
***Line 6: Char 22: error: invalid use of member 'freq' in static member function
int c1 = freq[a];
^~~~***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

static functions cannot access member objects. But if you make `comp` a non-static member function, you can no longer pass it to `sort`.

A solution is to make `comp` non-static and wrap it in a lambda in the call to `sort`, something like:

```
class Solution {
    map<int, int> freq;
public:
    bool comp(int a, int b){
        if(a!=b){
            int c1 = freq[a];
            int c2 = freq[b];
            if(c1!=c2)
                return c1<c2;
            else{
                return a>b;
            }
        }
        return a>b;
    }
    vector<int> frequencySort(vector<int>& nums) {
        for(int i:nums){
            freq[i]++;
        }
        sort(nums.begin(), nums.end(), [this](int a, int b) { return comp(a,b); });
        return nums;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++, calls to static members functions are not bound to any object and thus does not contain any implicit `this` pointer. On the other hand, each object receives its own set of data members. In your particular example, `freq` is a data member, `comp` is a static member function and `frequencySort` is a non-static member function. Calls to non-static member functions are bound to an object of the class and thus receive an implicit `this` pointer. The implicit `this` pointer is used to access data members inside the member function.

Now, in your particular case, the `comp` static member function cannot access data members without any explicit access to a class object, because there is no implicit `this` pointer for static member functions.

Making `freq` a static data member should solve the issue, and is probably what you want.

Comment: "Making `freq` a static data member should solve the issue,..." ?

Comment: ah yes, sorry, I have edited the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

**Static member functions** are not bound to any object i.e., they do not have a `this` pointer. As a result we cannot refer to `this` inside the body of a static member function. This **restriction** applies to both **explicit** uses of `this` as well as to **implicit** uses of `this` by calling a **non-static member**.

##### Solution 1

One way to solve this would be to make `freq` a **static data member**. [Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/qjMGm9KWQ)

##### Solution 2

Another way would be to make `comp` a **non-static member function**. [Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/tCstxAU05). Note that this may lead to other logical errors like `comp` can no longer be used as a comparator.